# Running under WinPE or WinRE

Tags: android, winpe

I am using Windows 10 64 bit,
when I choose **show in explorer** in my project I got this error,

" This application  only runs under WinPE or WinRE "

How can I browse my projects?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a piss poor answer but I thought I'd share anyway. Apparently there are two copies of `explorer.exe` in $PATH by default. One is in `C:\Windows\System32` and the other in `C:\Windows`. For me, for reasons I can't explain, the former is broken. Trying to start it results in the error message you showed. The latter, however, works fine.

Since the former copy is earlier in path it is what will be started by any program that tries to run explorer. I can think of a couple of possible terrible fixes for the time being.

1. Delete the copy in System32. Extremely not recommended.
2. Move `C:\Windows` ahead of `C:\Windows\System32` in path. Ultra extremely not recommended.
3. Symlink the copy that resides in `C:\Windows` to some other directory and put that directory ahead of `C:\Windows\System32` in path.

Option 3 is the only semi-reasonable one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately none of them worked

Comment: Thanx, it helped me to resolve the problem in my computer. For me, the solution was simply to rename the explorer.exe in C:\Windows\System32 (as it was an old version from 2015).